# Eksport Sheet To PDF, Save, or Update When File Name Was Exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a case, how to calculate the amount of water usage and payment bills for customer.
To solve the problem, I use two Google Form.

1. GF to collect data water usage, make formula to calculate how much water use, and calculate the bill.
2. GF to collect data, if customer have arrears in payments for the previous period.

Each form submission is stored in one Spreadsheet (with a different sheet)  and combined in another sheet, to be calculated.
This GF operated by different officers, because I haven't found a script to print the results after both forms are filled out, I compiled the script to Print (eksport Sheet) to PDF File, every one  filled out and sent  the forms.
To get the last data filled in and save it as a PDF, it doesn't matter which Form was filled in first, we need to create a script for Eksport Sheet To PDF and Save when the File Name did't exist, or Replace/ Update File when File with Same Name was exist. Base on [OVERWRITE FILE](https://Eksport%20Sheet%20To%20PDF,%20Save,%20or%20Update%20When%20File%20Name%20Was%20Exist) and `[Create PDF + Update Current File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239751/google-script-save-update-file?rq=1) , and some help  from @tanaike , here the script :

```
  function printSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

  var   sheet           =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var   fileid          =   sheet.getId();
  var   sheetKons       =   sheet.getSheetByName('DATA KONSUMEN');
  var   sheetCtkTagih   =   sheet.getSheetByName('CETAK TAGIHAN'); 
  var   fileCtkTagihid  =   sheetCtkTagih.getSheetId();                

  var   nameFile        = sheetCtkTagih.getRange('C4').getValue().toString() +".pdf";
  var   destinationFolder     = DriveApp.getFolderById(sheetKons.getRange('E4').getValue());


  var exportOptions ='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+fileid+
                '/export?&format=pdf' + 
                '&size=letter' + 
                '&portrait=true' + 
                '&fitw=true' + 
                '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + 
                '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=true' + 
                '&fzr=true' + 
                '&gid='+fileCtkTagihid;

  var request = {
                "method": "GET",
                "headers":{"Authorization": "Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},    
               "muteHttpExceptions": true
                };

 var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportOptions, request);
     pdf = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(nameFile);

 var deleteexisting = destinationFolder.getFilesByName(nameFile);
     if (deleteexisting.hasNext() === false) {
     // if no file is found then create it
    destinationFolder.createFile(pdf);
    } else {
   while (deleteexisting.hasNext()) {
        var updatedPDF = deleteexisting.next();
        Drive.Files.update({mimeType: 'application/pdf'}, updatedPDF.getId(), pdf);  
     }
    }
   }
```

This script goes well, as fix note, thanks to @tanaike for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Two Form Submission Sheet` and your script. But, in your script, `myVar = Drive.files.UPDATE(file, theFileID, uploadedBlob);` might be `myVar = Drive.Files.update(file, theFileID, uploadedBlob);`. For example, is this related to your current issue?

Comment: Thanks, to try help me again @Tanaike ,

Comment: Sorry if my explanation not clear.  What I mean with Two  Form Submission Sheet : I  have 2 Form, one Form Input Meter , and One Form  Payment arrears.  From that Two Form, I  use one spreadsheet to collect data (Form Submisiion), and than I make one sheet to  merge Data from it.  (where you help me to solve the  previous  script before ).  What i want was, every pair data from that two Form, I can Print one PDF File, no matter where the first I fill  the form, and then Update FIle, when the pair form filled yet.

Comment: Your suggestion to edit script  "UPDATE" to be "update"  not yet work. BTW  Thanks for it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Your suggestion to edit script "UPDATE" to be "update" not yet work. BTW Thanks for it.`, in my comment, `Drive.files.UPDATE` is modified to `Drive.Files.update`. Please modify not only `UPDATE` but also `files`. Please be careful about this.